# Block bounces - are complaint bounces the same as spam complaint?

Tags: bounce-management

In the salesforce documentation it says:

A block bounce occurs when the email server rejects the email because of a lack of authentication, or if the domain or IP address appears on a blocklist. **A subscriber who receives a block bounce is retried in the next email send.**

Within block bounces there are complains and spamblocked which confuses me with the previous statement. Don't spam and complaints automatically get suppressed and deactivated? Is it just that they are listed under block bounces and are an exception?

1001    Complaints  Your email is blocked due to complaints.
1002    Spamblocked The remote mail server has rejected this message due to characteristics of spam.

Answer (score 0):

Block bounce has multiple categories in it like - Complaint/Blacklist/Content/URL Block/Authentication

All these are temporary blocks with an option for either the recipient or marketer to fix. A subscriber can always go and mark an email as unspam. When that happens there will be no feedback sent from mail boxes to the ESP's. So, given the lack of continious feedback SFMC will always keep trying to send.

But, we all know it's a rarity when a subscriber goes and changes the status to unspam or remove a complaint. So, it's ideal for us to manually suppress them by using auto suppression in SFMC.

Hope this helps!

Cheers
Somu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the difference between this type of complaint and complaints that instantly unsubscribes a contact? And at what point would the feedback be sent to the ESP's after a block bounce complaint for it to become a deactivation of a subscriber?